# Asking the Bluetooth device to report blood glucose records greater than some date responds with Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth LE Blood Glucose Meter device called Accu-Chek (Aviva Connect).

I'm trying to filter the records: get only those that are later than **2016-10-23 20:01:02**. But the Bluetooth device responds with error.

In

```c
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didWriteValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
```

I get a NSError:
`Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=13 "The value's length is invalid."`

The documentation on Glucose Service states:

> When using the User Facing Time Filter Type, the format of the Operand is the User Facing Time Filter Type value followed by the applicable User Facing Time (sum of the Base Time and the Time Offset) value or value pair depending upon the Operator.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code of building the request where I add User Facing Time Filter Type and then User Facing Time (Base Time + Time Offset):

```c
- (void)reportFilteredRecords {

    if (self.peripheral && self.recordAccessControlPointCharacteristic) {

        NSMutableData *mutableData = NSMutableData.data;

        uint8_t opCode = 0x01; // Report stored records
        [mutableData appendBytes:(void*)&opCode length:sizeof(opCode)];

        uint8_t operator = 0x03; // Greater than or equal to
        [mutableData appendBytes:(void*)&operator length:sizeof(operator)];

        uint8_t filterType = 0x02; // User Facing Time (Base Time + Offset Time)
        [mutableData appendBytes:(void*)&filterType length:sizeof(filterType)];

        uint16_t year = 2016;
        uint8_t month = 10;
        uint8_t day = 23;
        uint8_t hour = 20;
        uint8_t minute = 1;
        uint8_t second = 2;

        uint8_t date[7];

        *((uint16_t*)date) = year;
        date[2] = month;
        date[3] = day;
        date[4] = hour;
        date[5] = minute;
        date[6] = second;

        [mutableData appendBytes:(void*)&date length:sizeof(date)];

        NSTimeZone *timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone;
        NSInteger secondsFromGMT = timeZone.secondsFromGMT;
        int minutes = (int)secondsFromGMT / 60 % 60;
        int hours = (int)secondsFromGMT / 3600;
        short userTimeZoneOffset = minutes + (hours * 60);

        uint8_t timeOffset[2];
        *((short*)timeOffset) = userTimeZoneOffset;

        [mutableData appendBytes:(void*)&timeOffset length:sizeof(timeOffset)];

        [self.peripheral writeValue:mutableData forCharacteristic:self.recordAccessControlPointCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
    }
}
```

Actually I tried to parse the `mutableData` to get all values back to see if they were encoded correctly. The data is encoded correct.

I found out that if I send 4 bytes – I get **no error**, but still no records in response:

```c
- (void)reportFilteredRecords {

    if (self.peripheral && self.recordAccessControlPointCharacteristic) {

        NSMutableData *mutableData = NSMutableData.data;

        uint8_t opCode = 0x01; // Report stored records
        [mutableData appendBytes:(void*)&opCode length:sizeof(opCode)];

        uint8_t operator = 0x03; // Greater than or equal to
        [mutableData appendBytes:(void*)&operator length:sizeof(operator)];

        uint8_t filterType = 0x02; // User Facing Time (Base Time + Offset Time)
        [mutableData appendBytes:(void*)&filterType length:sizeof(filterType)];

        const uint8_t val1 = (uint8_t)1; // <--- ?????
        [mutableData appendBytes:(void*)&val1 length:sizeof(val1)];

        const uint8_t val2 = (uint8_t)2; // <--- ?????
        [mutableData appendBytes:(void*)&val2 length:sizeof(val2)];

        const uint8_t val3 = (uint8_t)3; // <--- ?????
        [mutableData appendBytes:(void*)&val3 length:sizeof(val3)];

        const uint8_t val4 = (uint8_t)4; // <--- ?????
        [mutableData appendBytes:(void*)&val4 length:sizeof(val4)];

        [self.peripheral writeValue:mutableData forCharacteristic:self.recordAccessControlPointCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
    }
}
```

**FYI:**

The documentation on [Record Access Control Point (RACP)](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.record_access_control_point.xml)

The documentation on [Glucose Measurement](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.glucose_measurement.xml)

Comment: I won't answer for your issue, but `millisecondsFromGMT` should be named `secondsFromGMT`It's weird. Also, I'd recommend to use a `struct` (that mimic the doc). It's easier to read afterwards and you don't have to do all intermediary `appendBytes:length`.

Comment: I'm not sure that the `timeOffset` you used is the correct way. "sum of the Base Time and the Time Offset", I'd go with `date[4] += hours; date[5] += minutes;` and not append it. It feels weird but it seems to be the case. I'd read `0x2A08` value to check the device date, and use the iOS device difference as time zone instead of `currentTimeZone` (no sure that the device really use GMT).

Comment: Thank you @Larme for your comments.
I have tried:

            `date[2] += month;
            date[3] += day;
            date[4] += hour;
            date[5] += minute;
            date[6] += second;`

It doesn't help.